# MapBox fails when loading. How to know if it failed so I can restart?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am getting this error:

```
I/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: Request failed due to a connection error: Unable to resolve host "api.mapbox.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Having this error, I am not able to have a callback from `OnMapReadyCallback`.

I have a very poor internet connection (oh thank god for this). I noticed this and I cannot have any way this can be communicated to me. How would I know if mapbox failed so I can at least restart it again by maybe calling `getAsync` (?): `mMapViewPopular.getMapAsync(mOnMapReadyCallback);`

I am not sure how to handle failed instantiation of MapBox and restarting it again after some time.

Thanks!

Comment: You can listen to MapChange events with `MapView#addOnMapChangeListener` and look for `DID_FAIL_LOADING_MAP = 7;`

Comment: great! I'll be checking on that one